# Create 256 functions that do the same thing - creating a case-insensitive function - one liner to pass all parameters to a function?

Tags: linux, macos, bash, function, terminal

I want to create 256 functions that do the same thing

Basically I want a function that is able to be called case-insensitively.

Example: I want `applepie()` to be able to called case-insensitively:

```
applepie(){

for B in "$@";
do
another_function_in_my_bash_profile $B
blah blah 
# more stuff ...   
done

}
```

The most straightforward approach is to declare another 255 functions with some letter in caps:

```
Applepie(){

for B in "$@";
do
another_function_in_my_bash_profile $B
blah blah 
# more stuff ...   
done

}
```

and

```
aPplepie(){

for B in "$@";
do
another_function_in_my_bash_profile $B
blah blah 
# more stuff ...   
done

}
```

...

all the way to

```
APPLEPIE(){

for B in "$@";
do
another_function_in_my_bash_profile $B
blah blah 
# more stuff ...   
done

}
```

There are in total 256 (2 to the power of 8) of them

Is it possible to do it quickly? Or is there a more "built-in" approach like

```
case-insensitive appelepie(){

for B in "$@";
do
another_function_in_my_bash_profile $B
blah blah 
# more stuff ...   
done

}
```

or is it possible to do it like

```
case-insensitive APPLEPIE(){
  command -pass_all_parameters applepie
}
```

that can passes all the parameters to applepie instead of using a for loop `for B in "$@";`?

Answer (score 6):

You can fake a case-insensitive function name by defining all-lowercase function names and using `bash`'s trap for missing command names (requires `bash` 4, which you would need to install yourself on OS X):

```
command_not_found_handle () {
    cmd_name=${1,,}
    shift
    $cmd_name "$@"
}
```

So if `apple` is a function, but you try to call it as `ApPlE`, `command_not_found_handle` is called with the command as the arguments. The first line takes the first argument (`ApPlE`) and lower-cases it. Then it attempts to run `apple` with the original arguments.

Comment: +1 for being really smart; But is there a way to do it in lower version of bash?

Comment: Lowercasing is easy: `cmd_name=$(tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]' <<< "$1")`. However, trapping 'command not found' is not. You might define `command_not_found_handle` as above, then use it as a `DEBUG` trap, but see the `extdebug` option in the `bash` man page for more details. I don't think you can simulate the `bash` 4 functionality completely with `DEBUG`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty obtuse answer, and definitely not a one-liner, but here is how it can be done in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), with a little help from `bc` and `tr` (works on [osx](/questions/tagged/osx)):

```
funcname="applepie"

strlen=${#funcname}
numcombos=$((2 ** strlen))

for ((i=1; i<numcombos; i++)); do
    binstr=$(echo "obase=2; $i" | bc )
    zlen=$((1+strlen-${#binstr}))
    binstr=$(printf "%0${zlen}x" 0)${binstr}
    binstr=${binstr:1:$strlen}
    casename=""
    for ((j=0; j<strlen; j++)); do
    if [ ${binstr:$j:1} = 1 ]; then
        casename=${casename}$(tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]' <<< ${funcname:$j:1})
    else
        casename=${casename}${funcname:$j:1}
    fi
    done
    alias ${casename}=${funcname}
done
```

This does the following;

- gets the length of the function name
- figures out number of case combinations (2^n)
- loops over each combination
- turns the combination number into a string of binary digits
- Fiddles the string of binary digits so it is the same length as the function name
- indexes through each char of the function name and string of binary digits and does a toupper() case change only if the corresponding binary digit is 1
- reassembles the chars to a string
- does a bash alias from each combination to the function name

Assumes the function is defined, and has an all-lowercase name.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way using pure bash - and a recursive function.  I normally run a mile when I see recursive functions, but in this case it works quite nicely:

```
funcname="applepie"

function cr {
    if [ "$1" ]; then
        cr "${1:1:${#1}}" "${2:1:${#2}}" "${3}${1:0:1}"
        cr "${1:1:${#1}}" "${2:1:${#2}}" "${3}${2:0:1}"
    else
        alias $3=$funcname
    fi
}

cr $funcname $(tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]' <<< $funcname) ""
```